# How to divide string into substring in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and i am trying to divide and store a part of a string

```
this.chartIdSelector="Bulletsavings-140"
this.opportunityId = +this.chartIdSelector.substring(this.chartIdSelector.lastIndexOf('-') + +1);
```

This returns 140 back but if i include any alphabet it returns NAN

```
this.chartIdSelector="Bulletsavings-14av0"
this.opportunityId = +this.chartIdSelector.substring(this.chartIdSelector.lastIndexOf('-') + +1);
```

NAN

Comment: So remove the `+` from `+this.chartIdSelector`

Comment: Oh, it was this easy thank you so much

Comment: Unary plus (`+`) will try to convert the final value to a number. Since in the second example the final value contains a character, it will return `NaN` (Not a Number)

Answer (score 3):

As I already commented, remove the unary plus, also no need to `+ +1`

```js
let chartIdSelector="Bulletsavings-14av0"
let opportunityId = chartIdSelector.substring(chartIdSelector.lastIndexOf('-') +1);

console.log(opportunityId)
```

And in your case, just use split:

Here assuming only one dash in the string

```js
let chartIdSelector = "Bulletsavings-140"
let opportunityId = chartIdSelector.split("-")[1] 
console.log(opportunityId)
chartIdSelector="Bulletsavings-14av0"
opportunityId = chartIdSelector.split("-")[1] 
console.log(opportunityId)
```

Possibly more than one dash (but ID still at the end) - use pop:

```js
let chartIdSelector = "Bullet-savings-140"
let opportunityId = chartIdSelector.split("-").pop()
console.log(opportunityId)
chartIdSelector="Bullet-savings-14av0"
opportunityId = chartIdSelector.split("-").pop()
console.log(opportunityId)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use split

Here I use slice(-1) to get the last element from the array of the split, in case there are more than one dash in the string

```js
let chartIdSelector = "Bulletsavings-14av0"
let opportunityId = chartIdSelector.split('-').slice(-1)[0] 


console.log(opportunityId)
```

Comment: For getting last element from array

Comment: Oh ok, sorry about that, and thank you, next time I will watch out for that.

Comment: Good idea to consider such cases. I chose `split("-").pop()` since it is easier to read

Answer (score 0):

Rahul !

Just remove the plus sign. Keep as

```
this.chartIdSelector="Bulletsavings-140"
this.opportunityId = this.chartIdSelector.substring(this.chartIdSelector.lastIndexOf('-') + +1);
```